# Xamarin Android - How to find location of failure

Tags: android, xamarin, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

I am studying Xamarin in Action and my practise application fails when I am deploying it to Android. Below is stack trace (There is much more than this and I am just pasting what I think is more relevant). I am finding it hard to figure out the location where the app is crashing. App never loads and always crashes when I debug it. How can I find the location of failure. As can be guessed, I am new to development with IOC. I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio to develop the app

```
Searching for '__android_log_print'.
Probing '__android_log_print'.
Found as '__android_log_print'.
 UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
 Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in <7802aa64ad574c33adca332a3fa9706a>:0 
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <7802aa64ad574c33adca332a3fa9706a>:0 
   at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (System.Int32 resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x0005a] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
   at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxLayoutInflater.Inflate (System.Int32 resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x0003e] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Binding\Droid\Views\MvxLayoutInflater.cs:137 
   at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.CommonInflate (System.Int32 resourceId, Android.Views.ViewGroup viewGroup, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x00013] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Binding\Droid\BindingContext\MvxAndroidBindingContext.cs:52 
   at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.BindingInflate (System.Int32 resourceId, Android.Views.ViewGroup viewGroup, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Binding\Droid\BindingContext\MvxAndroidBindingContext.cs:36 
   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerAdapter.InflateViewForHolder (Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, System.Int32 viewType, MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext) [0x0000d] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross-AndroidSupport\MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView\MvxRecyclerAdapter.cs:173 
   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerAdapter.OnCreateViewHolder (Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, System.Int32 viewType) [0x00018] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross-AndroidSupport\MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView\MvxRecyclerAdapter.cs:155 
   at Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView+Adapter.n_OnCreateViewHolder_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_I (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_parent, System.Int32 viewType) [0x0000f] in <aa282e0b3937455a861deaefaef6659d>:0 
   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.e4bc17a2-2281-4b4b-a324-001bbf355990(intptr,intptr,intptr,int)
   --- End of managed Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException stack trace ---
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2101)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1115)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
    at mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.recyclerview.MvxRecyclerAdapter.n_onCreateViewHolder(Native Method)
    at mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.recyclerview.MvxRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MvxRecyclerAdapter.java:59)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6365)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5563)


    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5448)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5444)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3600)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3329)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3867)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.

Unhandled Exception:
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.e4bc17a2-2281-4b4b-a324-001bbf355990(intptr,intptr,intptr,int)
```

**List View Class into which recycler is embedded:**

```
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/ApplicationName")]
    public class ListOfElementsView : MvxAppCompatActivity<Elements>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.elements_view);

            var elements_list_view_toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.elements_list_view_toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(elements_list_view_toolbar);

            var elements_view_recyler_view = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.elements_view_recyler_view);
            elements_view_recyler_view.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        }
    }
}
```

**elements_view.axml content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/elements_list_view_toolbar_layout">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/elements_list_view_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/elements_list_view_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.recyclerview.MvxRecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/elements_view_recyler_view"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Elements" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**element_recycler_view.axml content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/field1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Field1"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/field2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/field1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="4sp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Field2"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/field3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/field1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="4sp"
    local:MvxBind="Text Field3"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also getting below warning recently. Is any of my configuration incorrect or improperly used?

`The element 'FrameLayout' has invalid child element 'mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.recyclerview.MvxRecyclerView'. List of possible elements expected: 'AbsoluteLayout, ViewGroup, View, ActionMenuView, LinearLayout, AdapterViewFlipper, AdapterViewAnimator, AdapterView, AnalogClock, AutoCompleteTextView, EditText, TextView, Button, CalendarView, FrameLayout, CheckBox, CompoundButton, CheckedTextView, Chronometer, DatePicker, DialerFilter, RelativeLayout, DigitalClock, ExpandableListView, ListView, AbsListView, Gallery, AbsSpinner, GridLayout, GridView, HorizontalScrollView, ImageButton, ImageView, ImageSwitcher, ViewSwitcher, ViewAnimator, MediaController, MultiAutoCompleteTextView, NumberPicker, ProgressBar, QuickContactBadge, RadioButton, RadioGroup, RatingBar, AbsSeekBar, ScrollView, SearchView, SeekBar, SlidingDrawer, Space, Spinner, StackView, Switch, TabHost, TableLayout, TableRow, TabWidget, TextClock, TextInputTimePickerView, TextSwitcher, TimePicker, ToggleButton, Toolbar, TwoLineListItem, VideoView, SurfaceView, ViewFlipper, ZoomButton, ZoomControls, android.webkit.WebView, android.gesture.GestureOverlayView, TextureView, ViewStub, fragment, Mvvm....   App.Droid\Resources\layout\elements_view.axml   19`

Comment: why do you think this has anything to do with IOC?

Comment: I think below is where code is failing but am not sure. I say it may be IOC because Xamarin internally does the coupling for me

`var elements_view_recyler_view = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.elements_view_recyler_view);
            elements_view_recyler_view.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));`

Comment: NotFoundException - sounds like it cannot find your RecyclerView

Comment: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0` Check your layouts and the ID's you are using. Did you provide a itemtemplate for your RecyclerView?

Comment: Check your Layouts, as I know you must not use other characters as A to Z, 0 to 9, and '_' to name resources.